# VS 2015: I have to re-add EF Core Tools every startup

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-core

I have an ASP.NET Core project with this inside the `project.json` file:

```
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "type": "platform"
},
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "NLog.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rtm-alpha5",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview2-final"
},

"tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview2-final"
 },
```

Once this is added to the project file and Visual Studio has restored the package, I can use `add-migration` from the package manager console.

But every single time I re-open Visual Studio the `add-migration` command is gone. Then I have to remove `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` from dependencies and add it back again for the command to work.

How can I fix this so the command is always available?

**Edit:**

I have now updated dependencies using nuget to this:

```
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
"NLog.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rtm-alpha5",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": {
  "type": "build",
  "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
},
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml": "1.1.0"
 },

 "tools": {
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
 },
```

Still the same problem.

**Edit 2:**

This method now only works if I add `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview2-final"` in `project.json`. If I use `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"` the command `add-migration` is not available at all.

But with preview2, I can still re-add it to project.json and re-start VS to get it working.

Comment: Did you try `dotnet restore` before `add-migraton`?

Comment: I did a `dotnet restore` and re-started VS = same problem.

Comment: Did you try to run VS 2015 as administrator?

Comment: Yes I have tried running as administrator but I still get the same problem